# Convert a string of an array to an array js

Tags: javascript

Why cant i convert this arr

```
let stringarr = "[2022/07/12, 2022/08/09]"
```

to this arr

```
let arr = JSON.parse(stringarr) ---> error
```

Unexpected token / in JSON at position 5

Comment: You need quotes around the dates.

Comment: @Barmar what if i dont have them. what can i do then to convert it to an array

Comment: Write your own parser, there's nothing built-in for this.

Comment: Fix the source of that data. It'll likely be much easier than writing a parser

Comment: Adding quotes wont work either tho

```let stringarr = "['2022/07/12', '2022/08/09']"
let arr = JSON.parse(stringarr)```

error

Comment: JSON requires double quotes, not single quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not valid JSON, since the array elements aren't quoted.

If the array elements are all dates formatted like that, you could use a regular expression to extract them.

```js
let stringarr = "[2022/07/12, 2022/08/09]"
let dates = stringarr.match(/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/g);
console.log(dates);
```

Answer (score 1):

> what can i do then to convert it to an array

There are several ways to do that, if the format of the string stays like this. Here's an idea.

```js
console.log(`[2022/07/12, 2022/08/09]`
  .slice(1, -1)
  .split(`, `));
```

Or edit to create a valid JSON string:

```js
const dateArray = JSON.parse(
  `[2022/07/12, 2022/08/09]`
    .replace(/\[/, `["`)
    .replace(/\]/, `"]`)
    .replace(/, /g, `", "`));
    
console.log(dateArray);
```

Or indeed use the `match` method [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73067629/58186) supplied.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regexp = /\d+\/\d+\/\d+/g;
const stringarr = "[2022/07/12, 2022/08/09]";

const arr = [...stringarr.matchAll(regexp)];
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's to much simple .

As your input is a valid array in string format. So, remove [ ] brackets and split with comma (,). Then it automatically generates an array.

```
let stringarr = "[2022/07/12, 2022/08/09]";
let arr = stringarr.replace(/(\[|\])/g, '').split(',');
```

Output:

```
['2022/07/12', ' 2022/08/09']
```